# Create new array of objects if one key is same then add other key's value of those object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I want to filter down my array of object based upon the one key. If that key is same in other object then second value of object will be added. I have an array of object like below:

Input:

```
var myArray = [
{
_name : "Mike",
_amount : "7"
},
{
_name : "Julius",
_amount : "10"
},
{
_name : "Edison",
_amount : "2"
},
{
_name : "Mike",
_amount : "10"
},
{
_name : "Kate",
_amount : "0"
},{
_name : "Edison",
_amount : "10"
}
]
```

Output:

```
var myNewArray = [
{
_name : "Mike",
_amount : "17"
},
{
_name : "Julius",
_amount : "10"
},
{
_name : "Edison",
_amount : "12"
},
{
_name : "Kate",
_amount : "0"
},
]
```

Mike and Edison is repeated twice so _amount key's value added for those objects. Its little confusing for me. Please help me out. Thank you!

Comment: please edit your post, because the objects inside the array are not valid. the structure of an object literal is `{ name: value }` with colon instead of equal sign.

Comment: @NinaScholz, thank you for noticing. I will update it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and an object as reference for the inserted objects.

```js
var myArray = [{ _name: "Mike", _amount: "7" }, { _name: "Julius", _amount: "10" }, { _name: "Edison", _amount: "2" }, { _name: "Mike", _amount: "10" }, { _name: "Kate", _amount: "0" }, { _name: "Edison", _amount: "10" }],
    newArray = [];

myArray.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a._name]) {
        this[a._name] = { _name: a._name, _amount: 0 };
        newArray.push(this[a._name]);
    }
    this[a._name]._amount = (+this[a._name]._amount + +a._amount).toString(); // if you really
}, Object.create(null));                                                      // need strings

console.log(newArray);
```

As requested sorted by `_amount` descending

```js
var myArray = [{ _name: "Mike", _amount: "7" }, { _name: "Julius", _amount: "10" }, { _name: "Edison", _amount: "2" }, { _name: "Mike", _amount: "10" }, { _name: "Kate", _amount: "0" }, { _name: "Edison", _amount: "10" }],
    newArray = [];

myArray.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a._name]) {
        this[a._name] = { _name: a._name, _amount: 0 };
        newArray.push(this[a._name]);
    }
    this[a._name]._amount += +a._amount
}, Object.create(null));

newArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b._amount - a._amount;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Just one word "awesome". Thanks a lot

Comment: how we can sort newArray here based upon _amount?

Comment: with [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) ..? depending on the property, you need a callback for this.

Comment: Yes based upon _amount property. Could you please update the answer. Thank you

Comment: Thank you Nina. I am new to JavaScript and was struggling since yesterday.

Comment: The _amount s are not of string type :))

Comment: @Redu, later yes for lazy sorting.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of ES6 this is how it is done.

```js
var myArray = [
{
_name : "Mike",
_amount : "7"
},
{
_name : "Julius",
_amount : "10"
},
{
_name : "Edison",
_amount : "2"
},
{
_name : "Mike",
_amount : "10"
},
{
_name : "Kate",
_amount : "0"
},{
_name : "Edison",
_amount : "10"
}
],
result = myArray.reduce((p,c) => {var o = p.find(e => e._name == c._name);
                                  !!o ? o._amount = (o._amount*1+c._amount*1)+"" : p.push(c);
                                  return p;},[]).sort((a,b) => b._amount-a._amount);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to use is a map where you store the keys (names) and their corresponding amounts. You add to the corresponding amount for a key if you encounter it once again. You can then go through the map and add objects to an array.

```
var myArray = [
{
_name:"Mike",
_amount: 7
},
{
_name:"Julius",
_amount: 10
},
{
_name:"Edison",
_amount: 2
},
{
_name:"Mike",
_amount: 10
},
{
_name:"Kate",
_amount: 0
},{
_name:"Edison",
_amount: 10
}
];

var map = {};

for (var i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++) {
    var key = myArray[i]['_name'];
    var amount = myArray[i]['_amount'];
    if (!map[key]) {
        map[key] = amount;
    } else {
        map[key] += amount;
    }
}
var outputArray = [];
for (var key in map) {
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        outputArray.push({_name: key, _amount: map[key]});
    }
}
```