# Remove object in Array of Objects if few key-value pair are same and another key-value are less than other object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have this type of object

```
var array = [ 
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 5 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 4 },
 { "foo": 2, "bar": 1, "baz": 3 },
 { "foo": 2, "bar": 1, "baz": 7 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 3, "baz": 4 } 
]
```

and If 'foo' and 'bar' key values are same then choose key 'baz' greater value and remove other objects.

like this

```
[ { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 5 },
{ "foo": 2, "bar": 1, "baz": 7 },
{ "foo": 1, "bar": 3, "baz": 4 } ]
```

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49305210/2129071) but it's not working for me.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51088882/2129071) is not like my question.

So, what is the solution in underscore/lodash library or in javascript only.

Comment: [This questions appears to be very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44982659/215552) to yours. You might study the answers to see if you can improve your solution.

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you can group by the combination of the value of `foo` and `baz`. Then map the result, and select the object with the highest `baz` value in each group:

```js
var array = [ 
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 5 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 4 },
 { "foo": 2, "bar": 1, "baz": 3 },
 { "foo": 2, "bar": 1, "baz": 7 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 3, "baz": 4 } 
]

var result = _.map(
  _.groupBy(array, o => `${o.foo}-${o.bar}`),
  g => _.maxBy(g, 'baz')
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With vanilla JS you can reduce the array into an object (the accumulator), using a similar convention for the accumulator key (combination of `bar` and `baz`). Whenever an object from the array, and an object stored in the accumulator have the same key, the one with the highest `baz` value is kept.

```js
const array = [ 
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 5 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 4 },
 { "foo": 2, "bar": 1, "baz": 3 },
 { "foo": 2, "bar": 1, "baz": 7 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 3, "baz": 4 } 
]

const result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, o) => {
  const key = `${o.foo}-${o.bar}`
  
  if(!r[key] || r[key].baz < o.baz) r[key] = o
  
  return r
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to sort the array by ascending order of `foo` and `bar` and descending order of `baz` and then do a `reduce`.

```js
var array = [ 
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 5 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 4 },
 { "foo": 2, "bar": 1, "baz": 3 },
 { "foo": 2, "bar": 1, "baz": 7 },
 { "foo": 1, "bar": 3, "baz": 4 } 
];

const res = array
  .sort((a, b) => a.foo - b.foo || a.bar - b.bar || b.baz - a.baz)
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const prev = acc[acc.length - 1] || {};
    if (!(curr.foo === prev.foo && curr.bar === prev.bar)) acc.push(curr);
    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37377168/2129071) and it's working for me,

this is the solution

```
var result = ab.reduce((p,c) => {var o = p.find(e => e.foo === c.foo && e.bar === c.bar);
!!o ? o.baz = (o.baz > c.baz ? o.baz : c.baz) : p.push(c);
return p;},[]);
```

but I didn't understand the flow of this code. So, I decided to extend the code and tried to understand the code

So, First I read about [reduce](https://underscorejs.org/#reduce) and [find](https://underscorejs.org/#find) and extended the code

```
var result = ab.reduce((newArray, singleObj) => {
  var sameKeyValueObj = newArray.find(obj => {
    return obj.foo === singleObj.foo && obj.bar === singleObj.bar
  });
  sameKeyValueObj ? sameKeyValueObj.baz = (
    sameKeyValueObj.baz > singleObj.baz ? sameKeyValueObj.baz : singleObj.baz
  ) : newArray.push(singleObj);
  return newArray;
}, []);
```

This is an understandable solution for me now. If someone has another good solution then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do first [**orderBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy) ... then [**keyBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#keyBy) and lastly [**values**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#values) to get what you need:

```js
var array = [ { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 }, { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 5 }, { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 4 }, { "foo": 2, "bar": 1, "baz": 3 }, { "foo": 2, "bar": 1, "baz": 7 }, { "foo": 1, "bar": 3, "baz": 4 } ]

const result = _.values(_.keyBy(
   _.orderBy(array, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']), x=>`${x.foo}-${x.bar}`))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can [**chain**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chain) it as well via:

```
const result = _(array)
  .orderBy(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
  .keyBy(x => `${x.foo}-${x.bar}`)
  .values()
  .value()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 },
  { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 5 },
  { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 4 },
  { foo: 2, bar: 1, baz: 3 },
  { foo: 2, bar: 1, baz: 7 },
  { foo: 1, bar: 3, baz: 4 }
];

const result = array.reduce((result, obj) => {
  const resultObj = result.find(resultObj => obj.foo === resultObj.foo && obj.bar === resultObj.bar);

  if (!resultObj) {
    return [ ...result, obj ];
  }

  if (resultObj.baz > obj.baz) {
    return result;
  }

  return [ ...result.filter(obj => obj !== resultObj), obj ];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```